# NC0 randomness vs. non-uniformity

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-complexity, computer-science, computation

In

> Ajtai and Ben-Or. A theorem on probabilistic constant depth
> Computations. STOC '84, 1984

Ajtai and Ben-Or show a non-uniform derandomization of BPAC0.

Is there a similar relation known for probabilistic and non-uniform NC0?
Or is it an open problem?

Comment: This question would be a better fit to https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi @domotorp, thanks I posted it there (hope I am not making more mess by doing that.) https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/52470/nc0-randomnes-vs-non-uniformity